# Show if the following sets are open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm doing some problems and there are some to which I simply don't have an answer.

> Are the following sets open or closed?
>
> 1. $(0,1)\text{ embedded in }\mathbb R^2\colon\{(x,y)\mid x\in(0,1),y=0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$
> 2. $\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\le x+y\le 1, z=0\}\subset\mathbb R^3$
> 3. $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb R_{++}$

The thing that confuses me is the fact that the set being embedded into a higher dimension while setting one of the variables constant.

For the set 3, would the answer differ if instead we had $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$? Do I understand correctly that the latter is neither closed nor open?

Thanks.

Comment: About 3 I am not sure. But obviously, 1. is neither open nor closed, 2. is closed and not open.

Comment: Yes: the set $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ is neither open nor closed in $\Bbb R$. It **is** closed in the positive reals, however, since its only limit point in $\Bbb R$ is $0$.

Comment: "The thing that confuses me is the fact that the set being embedded into a higher dimension while setting one of the variables constant."  In general that is dead givaway they can not be open-- any neighborhood will have points pertruding out in the higher dimensions.  For example in question with a neighborhood with radius $\epsilon$ around point $(x,0)$ will contain points $(w,\delta)$ where $\delta\ne  0$ so $(w,\delta)$ is not in the set so the set is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set

$$ A:=\{x\in]0,1[, \;y=0\} \subseteq \Bbb R^2 $$

is neither open nor closed. In fact, if it was open, taking $z=(1/2,0)\in A$, there should be an open disk $B^0(z;r)$ with $r>0$ such that $B^0(z;r)\subseteq A$. This is absurd since for example $(1/2,r/2)\in B^0-A$.

If it was closed, it should contain the limit of the sequence $\big((1/n,0)\big)_{n=2,3,4,\ldots}$ of $A$, i.e. $(0,0)$, absurd.

The set

$$B:=\{0\leq x+y\leq1, \;z=0\} \subseteq \Bbb R^3 $$

is not open by a similar argument we used for $A$. It is closed: if $(x_n, y_n, 0)$ is a sequence of $B$ convergent to $(x, y, 0)$, then $x_n\to x, y_n\to y$, and hence

$$ 0\leq x_n+y_n\leq 1 \;\;\implies\;\; 0\leq x+y\leq1 $$

i.e. $(x,y,0)\in B$.

The set

$$ C:=\{1/n \;:\; n\in\Bbb N\} \subseteq\Bbb R_+ =\{x\geq 0\}$$

is neither open (see above argument) nor closed ($\lim 1/n=0\notin C$), and that  regardless of whether C is a subset of $\Bbb R_+$ or of $\;\Bbb R$.

If $\Bbb R_{++}$ denote the set $\{x>0\}$, $C$ is closed in $\Bbb R_{++}$ as proved in the answer of @TheSilverDoe.

Answer (score 1):

1. is not closed, because for all $n$, the point $(1/n, 0)$ is in the set, but the sequence $(1/n, 0)$ tends to $(0,0)$ which is not in the set. It is neither open, because $(1/2,0)$ is in the set, but $(1/2, \varepsilon)$ is not in the set, for any $\varepsilon \neq 0$.

2. is closed, as the preimage of the closed subset $[0,1] \times \lbrace 0\rbrace$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the application $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,z)$. You deduce by connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that it is not open.
3. is not open because $1$ is in the set but $1+\varepsilon$ is not in the set, for any $\varepsilon \neq 0$. It is closed because you can write its complement in $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ as
   $$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{1}{k+1}, +\infty \right) \setminus \left\lbrace 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ..., \frac{1}{k}\right\rbrace$$
   which is an union of open sets (each term of this union being open as an open set minus a finite number of elements).

Answer (score 1):

> "The thing that confuses me is the fact that the set being embedded into a higher dimension while setting one of the variables constant."

EXACTLY!!!!!

In general that is dead giveaway they can not be open-- any neighborhood will have points pertruding out in the higher dimensions.  For example in question 1) with a neighborhood with radius $\epsilon$ around point $(x,0)$ will contain points $(w,\delta)$ where $\delta\ne  0$ so $(w,\delta)$ is not in the set so the set is not open.

Same thing with question 2).

> For the set 3, would the answer differ if instead we had {1n∣n∈N} as a subset of R

It makes *all* the difference in the world!

$0\in \mathbb R$ and $0\not \in \mathbb R_+$.

In $\mathbb R$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = 0$ so $0$ is a limit point of the set.  So the set is *not* closed.

But in $\mathbb R_+$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ non-existent. We show that for any $x \in \mathbb R$ that $x$ is not a limit point of the set.  so the set has no limit points and therefore *is* closed.